# Why does docker-compose up say it can't find dependencies for zingchart and multiselect?

Tags: vue.js, docker-compose, multi-select, zingchart, vue-multiselect

I would highly appreciate if someone had a solution for this, as I've been scratching my head with it for weeks..

So here's the problem : I have a Vue-Application which uses [ZingChart-Vue](https://www.google.com/search?q=zingchart+vue&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIE849IE849&oq=zingchart+vue+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3.4286j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Vue-Multiselect](https://github.com/vueform/multiselect). When i do `npm run serve` it perfectly serves, at port 8080. When I do `npm run build`, it perfectly builds. However, when I do docker-compose up, these two things ([ZingChart-Vue](https://www.google.com/search?q=zingchart+vue&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIE849IE849&oq=zingchart+vue+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3.4286j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Vue-Multiselect](https://github.com/vueform/multiselect)) mess it up.

Here's the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOXgk.png

This application is meant to be used for a CI/CD pipeline using github actions, but of course it gives an error too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFAQK.png

Here is the package.json file: https://www.codepile.net/pile/QeboY1mw

Here is the package-lock.json file: https://www.codepile.net/pile/NDGRXY90

Here's the docker file:

```
FROM node:12-alpine as application_modules

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Test and lint and Prod build
FROM node:12-alpine as prod_build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . . 

COPY --from=application_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

RUN npm test && npm run lint && npm run build

# Install Server dependencies
FROM node:12-alpine as server_modules

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY container-package.json ./package.json

RUN npm install

# Start Server
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=prod_build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

COPY --from=server_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY server.js ./

COPY container-package.json ./package.json

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Did you run `npm update`?

Comment: @bassxzero thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work after doing npm update unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer - Make sure you install Git on the pipeline (probably best to do it right after you install node!)